# Android MediaPlayer will not play sound on newer APIs

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer

I've been using this code and it plays sound just fine on Froyo and Gingerbread (and I assume Honeycomb as well as my friends have used it):

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);

Button clicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clicker);

clicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){

            mp.start();

        }
    });
```

The audio I'm using is in WAV format. I've checked it to make sure it's not corrupted and it's fine. This code and sound file still run correctly on Gingerbread.

On Ice Cream Sandwich and JellyBean devices (a galaxy nexus and a nexus 7 respectively) this code does not work. No sound is played. There's nothing put in logcat. I've searched through the Internet and asked my friends for ideas and I can't come up with anything.

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: I think you should put more debug statements in your code.  Why don't wrap the call inside an IllegalStateException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the call in an IllegalStateException, run it thru the debugger and see what you are getting.  Also set a boolean isPlaying=mp.isPlaying(); and check its value.  Also try a mp.reset() before starting and see it it works.

Also see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnErrorListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener%29

Go ahead and inplement MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener and register the method with the media player.  See what error you get.

Comment: I seem to be getting an Illegal State Exception error (-38, 0). Thanks, I'm a step closer to solving this now! mp.reset() did not help by the way.

Comment: Was able to solve it by rearranging code and using prepare(). Thank you again for all your help!

Comment: @RobS.,how did you use prepare()? prepare() is automatically called by create().